# While page loading window resize function is not called which is in window.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, window-resize

I have a method `setSize()`, which is in windows resize method.

My problem is, that while page is loading in url, if I turn my iPhone from portrait to landscape or landscape to portrait, then window's resize function is not called. After page loads it gets called.

"Also I was waiting for all image into DOM to get loaded once."

What should I do to make `setSize` method call itself *while* page is loading?

```
window.onload = function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        setSize();
    });
}
```

Comment: You can actually see it in your code, you're saying, "window.onload", which would call anything inside it, only when window is finished loading everything.

Comment: yes it is called once loading finish...want that function execute while page loading

Comment: I'd just wrap the function in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... }` instead of `window.onload`. Then it'll execute when the document has been read (the first chance to use jQuery) but before all other content has finished loading. Not using 'real' event listeners isn't great practice anyway. Like this : `$(function() {$(window).resize(setSize)});`.

Comment: If I use $(document).ready(function() { ... }  instead of window.onload. then    my program will get disturbed I have some images to load. those will not be appear.

Comment: Then I guess there isn't more choice than checking if these images are cached - if not then run `setSize()` with `window.onload`, otherwise only listen for `onDOMready`. I don't believe there's anything in between. It might be a good idea to add this info to the question since it very much influences the total context.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, jQuery only runs after page load. You're going to have to use native JS.

Place:

```
window.onresize = setSize;
```

In a script tag in the head of your page.

Then, the window resize event listener be listening as soon as that script tag is loaded.

Noe that this won't work if the file / script containing `setSize` hasn't loaded yet.

`window.onload` registers that event listener when the page has *finished* loading, which isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: it's not working.. it's get called after page load completely.

Comment: Ow, I forgot, jQuery only runs _after_ page load.

Comment: yes I placed    <script>
            $(window).resize(function () {
                setFlipBookSize();
            });

        </script> 
in head tag

Comment: Errors? Or is it still only working after page load?

Comment: window.onresize = setFlipBookSize();  added in head script tag after all js files are included.

Comment: Remove the `();`. You're storing a reference to a function, not executing it.

Comment: window.onresize = setSize;  this is one also executing after page loads

Comment: Can you reproduce that in a fiddle?

Comment: page loading time I wont be extend much so it will not able to produce in fiddle for me .